# POST to Facebook page via CURL

Tags: php, facebook, post, curl

I've set up a script to post news to my facebook page via PHP

It worked for the last 2 years

Now, without notice it stopped working.

I correctly get the `access_token` but the second part returns this error

```
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

Here is the code

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
$postString = "client_id=KEY&client_secret=SECRET&type=client_cred";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
$access_token = str_replace( "access_token=", "", curl_exec($curl) );


$titolo = 'Test';
$link_pulito = 'test.html';
$testo_fb = 'Test';

$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'message' => 'MESSAGE',
        'name' => 'test',
        'link' => 'http://www.test.com/workshop/',
        'description' => 'test test test',
        'picture'=>'http://www.test.com/77818763a19937bdd82b25f26cef2522.jpg'
        );

// set the target url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGE/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  //to suppress the curl output 

$result= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: are you sure you get the access token correctly? You're simply assuming that the curl_exec() call worked and didn't return a boolean false.

Comment: yes, I can echo access_token and see it

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has changed the way of leasing tokens.
Please use the facebook PHP SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: A good answer is here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile

Comment: It seemes that FB changed something on Oct, 27 and previous screept are not working any more ...